# Send emails as a background process

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

I want to make a newsletter feature in my application. I need to send emails about 5000-6000 after I create a newsletter. When the newsletter is published it will create an email queue which will be stored in the database. Since it requires a lot of time I need to run it in the background. So I made a command to send the mail using YiiMailer and the email queue from the database.

My command is working, but it is getting terminated after some time without completing the job. Also I need to run it in the background, but now it is not. Any help appreciated.

My controller

```
public function actionSend(){
    $command = new MailQueueCommand("test", "test");
        $command->run(null);
        $this->render('index');

}
```

My MailQueueCommand.php

```
<?php


class MailQueueCommand extends CConsoleCommand
{

public function run($args)
{
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria(array(
            'condition' => 'success=:success AND attempts < max_attempts',
            'params' => array(
                ':success' => 0,
            ),
        ));

    $queueList = EmailQueue::model()->findAll($criteria);

    /* @var $queueItem EmailQueue */
    foreach ($queueList as $queueItem)
    {


            $mail = new YiiMailer();
            $mail->IsSMTP();                                     
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                            
            $mail->Username = 'xxxx';                            
            $mail->Password = 'xxxxx';                          
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                           
            $mail->Port = 587;

            $mail->setFrom('exmampl@gmail.com', 'Name');

        $mail->setTo($queueItem->to_email);

        $mail->setSubject($queueItem->subject);
        $mail->setBody($queueItem->message, 'text/html');

        if ($this->sendEmail($mail))
        {
            $queueItem->attempts = $queueItem->attempts + 1;
            $queueItem->success = 1;
            $queueItem->last_attempt = new CDbExpression('NOW()');
            $queueItem->date_sent = new CDbExpression('NOW()');

            $queueItem->save();
        }
        else
        {
            $queueItem->attempts = $queueItem->attempts + 1;
            $queueItem->last_attempt = new CDbExpression('NOW()');

            $queueItem->save();
        }
    }
}


private function sendEmail($mail)
{
    $sendStatus = false;

    if ($mail->send() > 0)
        $sendStatus = true;

    return $sendStatus;
}

}
?>
```

Comment: Nobody??please help me yii wizards..

Comment: Does `Cron` job not work for you? Reference link http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/07/php-cron-job/

Comment: I am sorry that i dont know how to use cron. :-(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on my experience in sending email notifications

The reason usually your mail job gets stopped in between is because usually there is time limit on php execution, and sending 5000,6000 mails will take a long time . Using a service like Amazon SES you can send 5 per second so that is like 1200 seconds or 20 mins ..most mail servers will give you similar or slower speeds, Typical php(CLI) execution time is 30 seconds, which is where your problem is.

What I do is send only 100-200 mails per batch, and run the console command through cron every one minute.It will be slightly slower but you will get there.

```
 $criteria = new CDbCriteria(array(
            'condition' => 'success=:success AND attempts < max_attempts',
            'params' => array(
                ':success' => 0,
            ),
            'limit'=>200,
        ));
```

Set up cron using `crontab -e`

```
* * * * * <path-to-yii>protected/yiic MailQueueCommand run &> /dev/null
```

Hope this helps..

**Note:** if actually using SES this won't be a problem as they queue all your requests and send them 5 per second, and there is no limit on queing really.

**Note:** cron is not like calling from command line you might have unexpected issues setting it up.

Comment: i am not using any mail server. I will be sending it directly from the script.

Comment: How will i run my console command throuh cron? Any idea??I dont have any idea about this cron thing!

Comment: cron is nothing but scheduler, you can run tasks every minute, once a week, on monday nights ets using cron. To do so you have to edit your crontab file using crontab -e as i mentioned above..then enter the line in my answer 5 stars mean run the command every minute.. you can refer cron tutorials such as this http://www.unixgeeks.org/security/newbie/unix/cron-1.html

Comment: just to clarify, you will be using a mail server irrespective of how you are sending it. A mail server like (gmail yahoo, or Amazon) processes your requests to send a email to so-and-so person, communicates with the recipient's mail server, and passes your message. The recipient mail server stores the message and displays it in their inbox as new mail. You may not run your own mail server but you will be using one to send any email.

Comment: Since i am testing it locally,i am using gmail as my smtp server.But on my server i have not set up any mail server but the mails are going directly from a php script using php mailer. How does it work then?? Please clarify.

Comment: i am assuming you are not changing your php mailer config between local and server , then on server it goes via gmail smtp as well. If you are using gmail, keep in mind google limits sending mails by 2,000 per day for app users and 500 for regular users see https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22839?topic=1526

Comment: Nop..i have changed the config in the server. It is sending from the script only.Not via gmail :( I am confused.

Comment: I am just a beginner. But I understand that php has got an ability to send emails directly from the script,when the script is online. :-D

Comment: hey.. php or for that matter no language can send mails without a server. Can you imagine the amount of spam that will be generated?. PHPmailer is just mail creation class. Check their documentation at https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer. You can post your config file on server, redacting username,password of course, I can confirm how mails are being sent.

Comment: you may want to read this answer to understand the process better http://stackoverflow.com/a/14217452/1900483

Comment: Thanks a lot Manquer for your help.That link was really helpful. I am now testing it with cron in centOS virtual server.Not yet get it working. But still trying!