# Bcc emails take long to send using YiiMail. Is there a way to speed it up?

Tags: php, mysql, email, yii

I have this function that whenever an admin posts a new announcement, it sends an email to all the users of the forum:

```
 $currentid = Yii::app()->db->createCommand("select id from content where id = (select max(id) from content)")->queryRow();
                Yii::app()->session['announcement_message'] = 'You have successfully created an announcement.';

                $url = Yii::app()->createAbsoluteUrl('announcement/view/id/'.  $currentid["id"]);
                if(Yii::app()->partyroles->isAdmin())
                    {
                        $this->emailAll($url);
                    }
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
```

the emailAll() is another function that I made to do the actual mail sending but since there could be 100's to 1000's of emails in the future, the sending would be slow! Whenever I click the "create" button, it usually takes around 30 seconds before it redirects back to the view page since it takes a while to send all of those emails.

My question is if there's any way to speed this up? Or is there any clever way to perhaps show the user that "Email's are being sent, please wait?"

Comment: see this answer for how to handle large mail Q's in Yii http://stackoverflow.com/a/20396924/1900483

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For such a number of recipients I would not send the emails from the script that creates the newsletter, but write *filter* for the emails and the other informations as job into a queue, which is then read by another process (e.g. triggered by cron job) that builds the list of emails using the filter and then sends the email. You could store the job with an id in the queue so that you could check with e.g. ajax if the job is done.

This will additionally allow your system to schedule the sending of emails if it is for some reason busy.

Comment: I don't completely understand what you're trying to say. Although I know what you're saying, I don't quite understand the logic. This is what my flow is for this function:


1. Admin Creates Post
2. actionCreate() queries most recent data to get the id of announcement and stores it into $url.
3. actionCreate() calls the emailAll() function passing $url.
4. emailAll() function sends the email.


Now from what I understand from you, you're saying that: when admin creates a post, the actionCreate() follows through while on a separate function, email list is being triggered?

Comment: @charlesisjan The time consuming part is to query the email addresses, pass them to the mail system and waiting for the mail system to write the mail into a queue. So if you just store the information what should be done, and the message for the post when the admin requests to send the post, e.g. in a file or in the database. Then you can do the actual processing within another process that reads the _job_  out of the file/database. So the admin does not need to wait 30sec to get a feedback. And _removes_ the risk of a connection lose that could otherwise happen within the 30sec(e.g. timeout).

Comment: Any tips on how I would go about running the email function in the background instead?

Comment: We use node.js for such tasks but that would require a server where you have rights to install sw or that has node.js installed. Otherwise you could launch php as cli vi a cron job or any other language the server supports.